# Getting exception while calculating the total of gridview cells

Tags: c#

while calculating the total of gridview cells i am getting this exception:
**Input string is not in correct format.**

Here is my code: any help pls:

```
 public decimal GetTotal()
 {
  decimal total = 0;
  foreach (GridViewRow _row in GridView1.Rows)
  {
  TextBox txt = (TextBox)_row.FindControl("TextBox1");
  total +=decimal.Parse( txt.Text);
  }
  return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your TextBox `TextBox1`has a non-decimal number (probably blank) in its text property in at least one row of the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Write it this way:

```
public decimal GetTotal() 
{  
    decimal total = 0;  

    foreach (GridViewRow _row in GridView1.Rows)  
    {  
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)_row.FindControl("TextBox1");  
        decimal decimalValue;
        if (decimal.TryParse(txt.Text, out decimalValue))
        {
            total += decimal.Parse(txt.Text);  
        }
    }  

    return total;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...that issue solved but not calculating the total, i am calling this from
rowdatabound event like below:


 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        TextBox txtTotalPrice = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("total");
        txtTotalPrice.Text = GetTotal().ToString();
   }

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the exception, first check to make sure you have a decimal number. To do this without throwing an exception, use `TryParse` method:

```
foreach (GridViewRow _row in GridView1.Rows)
{
TextBox txt = (TextBox)_row.FindControl("TextBox1");
decimal value;
if (decimal.TryParse(txt.Text, out value)
    total +=decimal.Parse( txt.Text);
}
```